# Jenkins X- error creating cluster registering all CRDs: failed to register the Commit Status CRD: the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-x

I am trying to install jenkins-x onto gke-cluster below are the doc which i am following -

while running command `jx create cluster gke --network=gke-vpc-network-dev --subnetwork=gke-vpc-subnet-dev --skip-login --cluster-name jenkins-x`

git cloned repo -
https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx-tutorial.git

Facing error:

```
? Configured Jenkins installation type: Serverless Jenkins X Pipelines with Tekton
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
Error creating commitstatuses.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource
ERROR: error creating cluster registering all CRDs: failed to register the Commit Status CRD: the server could not find the requested resource
error: registering all CRDs: failed to register the Commit Status CRD: the server could not find the requested resource
```

**Doc:**
https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/install-jx-on-gke/lesson.md

i was expecting below steps:

Jenkins Installation
Select Jenkins installation type: recommended is Serverless Jenkins X Pipelines with Tekton
A number of settings will be configured for you, such as installing an ingress controller.

If you are asked the name you wish to use with git: enter your GitHub user name

If you are asked the email address you wish to use with git: enter your GitHub email

You will be prompted for Domain .nip.io: Accept the proposed domain by pressing Enter

Do you wish to use < your GitHub user name > as the local Git user for GitHub server: y

Do you wish to use GitHub as the pipelines Git server: y

Workload build pack should default to: Kubernetes Workloads: Automated CI+CD with GitOps Promotion

Jenkins X should be installed on your Kubernetes cluster.